# Python Google Cloud Storage hangs occasionally - how do I detect and abort?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

Using Python 3.6 and the [Google Cloud python library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/index.html), I have a process that uploads a set of ~500mb files to Google Cloud Storage once per day. The script is running on an Ubuntu instance on Google Compute Engine that has plenty of disk space, RAM, etc. The uploading code basically looks something like this:

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("my-bucket")

for filename in filename_list:
    blob = bucket.blob(filename)
    blob.upload_from_filename("/path/to/" + filename)
```

About once each week, this operation hangs after uploading 3 or 4 of the 12 or so files that I have to upload. The [relevant documentation is here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage-blobs.html).

My question is: How do I wrap this to detect that it is hanging and then abort the operation and start it again? Is there a way to allot a certain amount of time for each iteration of the loop and break out if it takes too long?

Comment: two questions, 1) have you looked into chunking your files, I experienced similar issues with AWS, 2) have you looked into using their CLI, in my experience these tools are superior to Python when it comes to tasks like these.

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy I have looked into chunking -- in fact, I chunk them when I download them from their source. The files aren't particularly large, though... I use the CLI tools for some other reasons, but since the script performs some other tasks, I would prefer to keep the uploading in Python. Hence, if it's possible to recognize and recover from the hanging failure in Python, I'd prefer to do that.

Answer (score 1):

For such tasks, you need to use threads.
In a background thread (that is started after your upload begins) write a loop that will:

1. Use the stat function to get info about the file size.
2. Check difference in file size. If file size not increasing after 10 minutes, report error. This means your thread needs to send exit code to your main program.
3. If upload not complete, sleep for 2 minutes (or preferred time period).

Also, if your upload completes, set a variable (shared with thread) so thread will know it should exit.

Comment: You don't even need threads, you can use multiprocessing to start the download in a separate process, then monitor file size, see if process is still alive, and terminate the process if necessary from the main process.